# Get a running process dimensions excluding overlapping windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, process

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824573/7919921) to get an external process dimension (using Process.MainWindowHandle and GetWindowRect\DwmGetWindowAttribute functions Pinvoke).

But I need to get the dimension of the window **excluding any other process\window that hiding part\all of this process**, in other words, only the visible area of this MainWindowsHandle.

For example, how do I get only the red dashed area of Explorer.exe and VNC.exe in this screenshot?

[image: example]

Comment: It requires pinvoke.  Consider explaining why this is important so somebody can propose a better approach.

Comment: I had the same issue 1,5 year ago and what I did was to enumerate all HWND's based on their `Z` position on the screen. At the end you just have to subtract overlapped rects from the one you're needing.

Comment: @HansPassant I already use Pinvoke as mentioned, to get the window dimension. So I can use other WinApi functions as well. The reason I need to do that is to prompt the user if part of the application is covered by other window\menu even though it's still in front (which I determine by using GetForegroundWindow) and mark the problematic area.

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks. I've tried to do so based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27067603/7919921 , apparently, I had to run my process elevated so I can access another process internal handles, and it looks kind of unreliable, I got wrong Z order (even though my process was covered by unfocused windows, it was first in Z order)

Comment: I perhaps ought to point out a flaw in that master-plan.  "mark the problematic area" requires painting.  Painting requires a window.  In other words, you have to put a window with a transparent background on top of these windows.  That's possible, but the flaw is that this creates the very problem you are trying to solve :)

Comment: @HansPassant That what I already do (: I have a transparent win form over the window (using Form Region and Region.Exclude proprety). I know how to ignore my process when I check which process is in front and etc. All I have to do now is to 'include' the problematic area, so it can paint this area, so that why I ask if anyone got a creative solution for that.